# Can I have VS 2013 ignore certain syntax errors until I build?

Tags: visual-studio, syntax-error, visual-studio-2013, error-checking

For example, I could pretty much always do without the "not all code paths return a value" error squiggly.  This generally means I'm in the process of writing the method.  I don't need to be told it doesn't return a value.  If I forget to add a return value, VS can tell me that when it builds.  But I never want that while I'm working; it's annoying and usually tells me something I already know.

For another example, I could do without the errors that show up while I'm in the process of writing a switch statement, such as the one that tells me I don't have a break statement yet, as I'm still working on whatever case.

Comment: Tools -->Options--> Projects and Solutions --> General and deselecting the "Always show Error List if build finishes with errors".  or u can just unpin errors list and can open once u r about to build it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to disable "Show live semantic errors",

http://www.devcurry.com/2011/01/disable-squiggly-or-wavy-lines-in.html